# Annotate Array of Strings in GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm trying GSON for the first time, and at first glance the results are great.

I couldn't figure this one out:
in my json string I have an array with strings in it, with no specific name like this:

```
"addressLines": ["2860 SINT-KATELIJNE-WAVER"]
```

In this example it's only one, in the JSON Viewer it shows like:

```
0 - 2860 SINT-KATELIJNE-WAVER
```

I have a class AddressLine with a private String addressLine in it,
but I wouldn't know how to annotate this?

Comment: Have you tried `String[]` or `List<String>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be this...

```
@SerializedName("addressLines")
public List<String> addressLines;
```

Or this...

```
@SerializedName("addressLines")
public String[] addressLines;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the String array solution works great!
Thanks @323go & @BenjaminPaul!

Comment: @TomCB No problems :) Please accept the answer if it works so that someone else may find it useful.